# AlertDialog.Builder not dismissing android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have a AlertDiaog.Builder instance which I want to dismiss on NegativeButton click. then I want to execute a AyncTask. All this happens upon shaking my device.

currently, The AlertDialog.builder does not dismiss even after the AyncTask executes.

The showDialog() is executed from another button click where everything works perfect. This problem occurs only on device shake.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
    public void onShake(float force) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
        hour = hour+1;
        mins = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        timeString = hour+":"+mins+":"+today.second;
        showDialog(timeString, "");
        }
    public void showDialog(String timeString, String title)
    {

        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        builder.setTitle(title);
        builder.setMessage("Reaching at:"+" "+ timeString+"?");

        builder.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // Do nothing
                dialog.dismiss();
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
            {
                // Do nothing but close the dialog
                dialog.cancel();;
                new AddStatusTask().execute();

            }

        });


        alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
```

any help is appreciated

Comment: did i keep global referance of ur dialog to dissm on postexceute of asynctask?

Comment: @mtetno no I didnt. I am executing the same piece of code on another button click where it works fine. its only when the device is shaken this problem occrs

Comment: and this is in same activity right? u just wanna dismiss it on asynctask complete?

Comment: That is strange as the dialog will close on positive or negative even is there is no dismiss() or cancel(); Try with `builder.show();` instead of `alert = builder.create(); alert.show();`

Comment: Maybe it is a context issue? You use getActivity().

Comment: did u sloved the issue?

Comment: @greenapps your solution worked. Please post an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is strange as the dialog will close on positive or negative even if there is no dismiss() or cancel(); Try with `builder.show();` instead of `alert = builder.create(); alert.show();`.